# I GET array from API but when i try show it in the table it show me empty array (noob ReactJs)

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, mongodb, react-redux

I created a Be api I that exist a Get request to get all the tasks from this API ,
[image]

```
{
"tasks": [
    {
        "_id": "5f0b19c11f072e0984459ff5",
        "title": "some Edited random stuff ",
        "description": "some Edited random stuff",
        "creater": "vladi",
        "__v": 0
    },
    {
        "_id": "5f0b19d71f072e0984459ff6",
        "title": "vladi task ",
        "description": "vladi description",
        "creater": "vladi",
        "__v": 0
    }  ]
```

in my TaskReducer i make it

```
tasks: {
  tasks: []
  },
```

now in my fronted page i ask to see it all in a table

```
 <tbody>
                    {this.props.tasks.tasks.map((task, taskID) =>
                        <tr key={taskID}>
                            <th scope="row" >  2{task.title}</th>
                            <td >3{task.description}</td>
                            <td >4{task.creater}</td>
                            <td >5{task.dateCreated}</td>

                            <td >
                                <span className="pointer" onClick={() => this.handlerClickDeleteTask(task.taskID)}>delete  </span>
                                <span className="pointer" onClick={() => this.handlerClickViewTask(task.taskID)}>edit  </span>
                                <span className="pointer" onClick={() => this.handlerClickEditTask(task.taskID)}>view  </span>
                            </td>
                        </tr>

                    )}

                </tbody>
```

but when i open the table it look empty (even not showing the numbers there)
this is the link to the repository if someone have idea or think need more
https://github.com/VladiKonovalov/Fronted/blob/master/src/containers/Tasks.js

Comment: when your array is empty, so there is nothing to map, therefore even the hardcoded numbers are not rendered. start with a dummy array of data to first check your UI, then debug to see where your data structure goes wrong.

Comment: my array not empty ,it have information (the first code).. my TaskReducer empty cause i so it in some exmaple of codding he "clean' all inside and just keep the sclt

Comment: is the JSON the outcome of your code during runtime? `console.log(this.props.tasks.tasks)` ?

Comment: so if i Open my network i will see that been a GET TASKS call and even get Good response
but if i ask print to me in console.log(this.props.tasks.tasks) log i will see empty array and empty length

Comment: @Amir-Mousavi did you understand where the problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

under `usersActions.js` file you are setting users instead of tasks.

```
case "SET_TASKS":
    state = { ...state, users: action.payload }
    break;
default:
```

it should be like:

```
case "SET_TASKS":
    state = { ...state, tasks: action.payload }
    break;
default:
```

Comment: such a small and stupid mistake... thank you friend